# Double natural order not working as expected

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to implement selection sort using generics. To do that I receive a comparator (Because I wanted to use the method `Comparator#naturalOrder()` while testing).

The problem is that when calling it with a `Double` array it does not work, but when calling it with an `Integer` array instead, it works.
Here is the selection sort implementation I made:

```
public static<V> void selectionSort(V[] arr, Comparator<V> cmp){
    if (arr == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid array, can't be sorted");

    int minIndex = -1;
    for(int i = 0, j; i<arr.length; i++){
        for (j = i; j<arr.length;j++){
            if (minIndex == -1 || cmp.compare(arr[minIndex],arr[j])>0){
                minIndex = j;
            }
        }
        swap(arr, i, minIndex);
    }
}

private static<V> void swap(V[] arr, int i, int j) {
    V aux = arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=aux;
}
```

Here is the test that's failing:

```
@Test
public void selectionSortDoubleTest(){
    arrDouble = new Double[]{5.5,2.5,1.2,8.0};
    SelectionSort.selectionSort(arrDouble, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Double[]{1.2,2.5,5.5,8.0}, arrDouble);
}
```

And here is the test that works:

```
@Test
public void selectionSortIntegerTest(){
    arr = new Integer[]{2,5,7,1};
    SelectionSort.selectionSort(arr, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Integer[]{1, 2, 5, 7},arr);
}
```

The weird part is that in the first test the arrays differ at position `[1]`, so both start with 1.2, but then `arrDouble[1]` is 8.0 which doesn't make any sense.

The assertion error message I receive:

```
Arrays first differed at element [1]; 
    Expected :2.5
    Actual   :8.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minIndex` must be reset to -1 at each iteration of the outer loop. Otherwise you swap the previously found min element with the new one. Using a debugger makes it quite easy to spot such mistakes.